# Vuex - this.$store.commit or state.commit?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue. Is there a right and wrong way to commit a change to state? Both of the below examples work, so I'm trying to understand why / when to use one over the other?

```
import state from "../store/index";

state.commit('someMutation', data);
```

And if state *isn't* imported, it works like this:

```
this.$store.commit("someMutation", data);
```

Comment: i think this.$store.commit("someMutation", data); is better no need to import state wherever you want to use it

Comment: You must import if you want to use the store before vue mounts or from utility functions separate from your vue components (fairly common, I'd say). I also stay away from `this.$store` almost entirely because I think `mapActions` + committing from actions is cleaner. (So basically what Noah Stahl said) But I also don't think it's something to get too hung up on. Lastly, you are importing the **store** here, not the *state*. Trivial I know, but naming matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not necessarily a "wrong" way to change state, but taking the docs as a cue, using [$store.commit](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components) or [dispatching actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) is the way to go when using from components.

I always use actions since they can be async, typed in Typescript, and hide any complexity about state changes from my components.